# Value assigned from first view controller is not persisting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have got two view controllers say `NewGroupView` and `GroupsTabView`. I have to set bool value of second view controller from my first view controller. This is how im setting the values of the second view controllers from my first view controller.

```
NewGroupView *groupView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewGroupViewNC"];
NewGroupView *ngv = [NewGroupView new];
ngv->isGroupViewMode=YES;
groupView.isGroupViewMode = YES;
[self presentViewController:groupView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Following is the interface declaration of my second view controller.

```
@interface NewGroupView : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property(nonatomic,assign)    BOOL  isGroupViewMode;
@end
```

in my viewDidLoad method, I tried it print it as follows,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(isGroupViewMode ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```

But the issue is that it is always printing NO though I have set it to be YES.
why is that the assigned value is not persisting?

Comment: @meaning-matters stop write useless comments and answers. `->` is used to access instance variables.

Comment: check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/4831524

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Actually dot notation is used as setter/getter, and -> is not a setter . OP, why are you instantiating a NewGroupView and at the same time creating another one with new method?

Comment: @Sneak replace `.` with `->` and property with instance variable declaration will work. At least just tried to set and get variable in the same thread

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov I was talking about it not being the same as using dot notation, since it calls the setter and getter methods it differs from -> , I don't know if you edited the comment or if I am to tired and read your comment all wrong...however even if that isnt the problem in this case..

Comment: How to set and get variable in the same thread?

Comment: groupView->isGroupViewMode=YES; NSLog(groupView->isGroupViewMode ? @"Yes" : @"No");

Comment: the above code prints no though I have set it to be yes..why so?

Comment: why downvoted my question? :(

Comment: @user31231234124 Sneak already answered - `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` calls `viewDidLoad` implicitly and so you get `NO` before you set it to `YES`.

Comment: any alternatives?

Comment: for example move this code to `viewDidAppear` (as was already mentioned)

Comment: @user31231234124 Dude , alternatives for what? Thats the solution to your problem in my answer. You can not NSLog it in viewDidLoad, since it has not been set yet. add **viewDidAppear** and you will get the correct NSLog value there instead

Comment: ok thanks... i have handled it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in `NewGroupView` with code:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isGroupViewMode;
```

And write the following code in first view controller :

```
NewGroupView *groupView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewGroupViewNC"];

groupView.isGroupViewMode = YES;
[self presentViewController:groupView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you can check it using log from the second view controller (viewDidLoad method):

```
NSLog(@"%@",isGroupViewMode);
```

Alternativelty you can store the boolean value into NSUserDefault from first view controller and access this value from the second view controller.

Comment: @user31231234124 it seems your code is correct but you have a problem in another place. 1)check which is executed first - `viewDidLoad` or setting a bool variable to `YES`; 2)you set to YES 2 different variables - which one and when do you try to check?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov I agree with you. The viewDidLoad method will get called in instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, and he sets the BOOL value AFTER the viewDidLoad. Should move the NSLog to viewDidAppear or something. You should add it as an answer since that is the correct answer to this question btw.

Comment: `@property BOOL isGroupViewMode;` in second VC.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel why?

Answer (score 1):

```
NewGroupView *groupView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewGroupViewNC"];
```

Above line calls `viewDidLoad`, and this is where you print NSLog , the BOOL value is still "NO" , since it has not been set yet.

Now you call:

```
groupView.isGroupViewMode = YES;
```

But you can not see it in your NSLog since `viewDidLoad` has already been called from before.

**EDIT:**

As commented by @[VyachaslavGerchicov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575764/vyachaslav-gerchicov)

> the initial case with using of -> will work too.

Comment: Please add the addition that the initial case with using of `->` will work too.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Done

Answer (score 0):

Declare Your BOOL Property in .h file

```
@interface NewGroupView : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property(nonatomic,assign)    BOOL  isGroupViewMode;
@end
```

then synthesize it in .m file

```
@synthesize isGroupViewMode;


NewGroupView *groupView = (NewGroupView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewGroupViewNC"];
groupView.isGroupViewMode=YES;
[self presentViewController:groupView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

& Hope this will help you.